# override css content of :befor selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have loading GIF with bellow code

```
<style>
.se-pre-con {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100000000000;
  background: url('Preloader_11.gif') center no-repeat #fff;
}
.se-pre-con::before {
  content: 'Please Wait...';
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 28% 35%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
<div class="se-pre-con" id="loading" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Preview of above code
[loading Prview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRHTT.png)
I want to change content of `.se-pre-con::before` for different ajax from jquery to display different massages for different processes

Comment: Why are you not using html element instead of :before (pseudo element) ? just add and element install of ".se-pre-con" element and make the content dynamic

Comment: I can use html element, but this loading GIF is use on every ajax request so if i change this then it will effect on whole project so i want to use this for some specific ajax requests.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin) has a few good answers with explanation.